# Avoiding that two fields have the same values

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-office

I am using Access 2010.

I have a Table named `Person` : `Id(key), field1(int), field2(int)`.

I want to avoid that `field1` will be equal to `field2`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to query this table and want filter?

Comment: no.. with query it's ok. there is option to limit duplicate of 2 diffrent fields, when i insert data to this table?

Answer (score 5):

With your table in Design View, open its Property Sheet and set the table Validation Rule to `[field1]<>[field2]` like this ...

[image]

Note that if you omit the square brackets surrounding the field names, Access may convert them to text values ... `"field1"<>"field2"`.  You don't want that.

BTW, I typically change the Subdatasheet Name property to `[None]`, but that's not an issue related to the Validation Rule.